# Generate Random name fails in reset

Tags: scala

The below code works fine for the test cases:

1. name is generated for regex "[A-Z]{2}\d{3}"
2. name is not changed
3. does not have the same name as other robots

but fails for reset

1. Can have its name reset.

**Test case:**

```
val robot = new Robot()
val name = robot.name
robot.reset()
val name2 = robot.name
name should not equal name2
```

**Source Code:**

```
class Robot {
  val chars = ('A' to 'Z' )
  var name : String = {
    var num = 100 + Random.nextInt(899)
    var sb = new StringBuilder
    for (i <- 1 to 2 ) {
        sb.append(chars(scala.util.Random.nextInt(chars.length)))
    }
    sb.append(num)
    sb.toString()
  }

  def reset() : String = new Robot().name
}
```

Please help to fix this

Comment: changing the method name as def does not pass for test case 2 - name is not changed

Comment: The test case looks very much like the name *can* change. The `reset` method should change the name, not return a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
class Robot {
  var name : String = randomName()

  def randomName() = {
    val chars = ('A' to 'Z' )
    var num = 100 + Random.nextInt(899)
    var sb = new StringBuilder
    for (i <- 1 to 2 ) {
      sb.append(chars(scala.util.Random.nextInt(chars.length)))
    }
    sb.append(num)
    sb.toString()
  }

  def reset(): String = {
    name = randomName()
    name
  }
}
```

Note how `name` is not changed on subsequent access despite being assigned with method `var name : String = randomName()`:

```
val robot = new Robot()
robot.name // res0: String = RV417
robot.name // res1: String = RV417
robot.name // res2: String = RV417
```

This is because `var`'s value is memoized, meaning it is cached after the first initialisation. However, we can still change `var`'s value by forcing a re-assignment like so

```
def reset(): String = {
  name = randomName()
  name
}
```

which outputs

```
val robot = new Robot()
robot.name // res0: String = OE770
robot.reset()
robot.name // res2: String = PI287
```

Comment: This works from command line but not from IDE - Intellij. I am using spark-submit to run from command. Any particular reason why it does not work from IDE

Comment: I don't get any error. The value from robot.name and robot.reset().name is same

Comment: import scala.util.Random

class Robot {

  var name : String = randomName()

  def randomName() : String = {
    val chars = ('A' to 'Z' )
    val rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis)
    var num = 100 + rand.nextInt(899)
    var sb = new StringBuilder
    for (i <- 1 to 2 ) {
      sb.append(chars(rand.nextInt(chars.length)))
    }
    sb.append(num)
    sb.toString()
  }

  def reset() : String = {
    name = randomName()
    name
  }
}

Comment: it ("can have its name reset") {
//    pending
    val robot = new Robot
    val name = robot.name
    robot.reset()
    val name2 = robot.name
    name should not equal name2
  }

Comment: Please see edited answer. I've removed the `new Random(System.currentTimeMillis)` from `randomName`.

Comment: Could you please explain the reason behind removing new Random. This seems to work.